# PHP dynamic previous/next links

Tags: php

I have a table called "product".

I'm displaying all the data from PHP product view page by using the id parameter.

With my code:

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE id = $id ";
$select_product = $db->query($query);

while($row = $db->fetch_object($select_product)) {
    $status = $row->status;

    if($status == 'published') {
        $title = $row->title;
        echo $title;
    }

}
```

I can pull all the data I need. In this example I can echo the title.

But how do I display a dynamic next page link? That goes same for previous link.

When I try with this code:

```
$query = "SELECT id FROM product";
$select_ids = $db->query($query);

while($row = $db->fetch_object($select_ids)) {
    $ids = $row->id;

    echo $ids;
}
```

I can see all the pages from that table. In my case they are 20,21,22...28

Next, I've tried like this:

```
$query = "SELECT id from product";
$select_ids = $db->query($query);

if($select_ids->num_rows > 0) {
    $next = $id + 1;
    echo '<a href="' . $next . '">Next</a>';
} else {

}
```

With this code, my "next" link successfully goes to the next page. But, when it finishes with the result, in this case when I'm on page 28, the next dynamic link goes to empty page (29). Also this is not a good approach, because if some page, let's say 25 is deleted, the next link won't skip that page.

How can I improve that dynamic "next" link?

Comment: Use PDO in order to prevent SQL injection

Comment: You should query the next/previous rows and use their data to determine how and when to show the links

Comment: Thank you for your advice, Luca, but I'm using MySQLi OOP and it's perfectly safe. ;)

Comment: Hi, casraf. Yes, that's a good approach, but how do I do that with a code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first of all, you need two queries one for getting the data to display and another for counting the number of rows, also we'll need some additional variables.

Here comes the code:

```
$page = 1;
if(isset($_GET['page'])) {
    $page = $_GET['page'];
}

$numberOfResultsPerPage = 10;
$offset = $numberOfResultsPerPage * ($page - 1)

$count = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(id) as num FROM product");
while($row = $db->fetch_object($count)) {
    $numberOfRows = $row->num;
}

$query = "SELECT id FROM product LIMIT ". $offset.", ".$numberOfResultsPerPage;
$select_ids = $db->query($query);

while($row = $db->fetch_object($select_ids)) {
    $ids = $row->id;
    echo $ids;
}
if($page > 1) {
    echo '<a href="index.php?page=' . ($page-1) . '">Prev</a>';
}
if($page < ceil($numberOfRows / $numberOfResultsPerPage)) {
    echo '<a href="index.php?page=' . ($page+1) . '">Next</a>';
}
```

UPDATE:

In case you need to just find the next and previous product of the product this is the solution. It is not good if you'll have lots of products but in case the number of products is under 1000 there should not be any problems:

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
}

$query = "SELECT id from product";
$select_ids = $db->query($query);

$ids = array();
$i = 0;
while($row = $db->fetch_object($select_ids)) {
    $ids[$i] = $row->id;
    if($row->id == $id) {
        $index = $i;
    }
    $i++;
}
if(isset($ids[$index-1])) {
    echo '<a href="' . $ids[$index-1]. '">Prev</a>';
}
if(isset($ids[$index+1])) {
   echo '<a href="' . $ids[$index+1]. '">Next</a>';
}
```

Comment: Hi, KoKo. I've tried your code and I'm not getting any result. On this line I've set it like this: `$numberOfRows = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM product";` and the links are not displaying. That's because I'm already in a page that has passed a variable $id. `if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
 $id = $_GET['id'];
}` So, it must have some different logic related with that variable.

Comment: @user2519032 $numberOfRows should be the result of the query. It should be integer. You've just assign string to it. to test it out just assign the number of the rows you have in database.

Comment: @user2519032 also if you want to have one product per page change the $numberOfResultsPerPage = 1; In my example it'll display 10 products on each page.

Comment: Yes, I've already changed to $numberOfResultsPerPage = 1; I'm still trying to figure out the $numberOfRows...can you please edit your code?

Comment: I've tried again with the edited code, but it's not working. The links are not displayed. Also why using a $page variable. The pages shows the full content from the $id variable and I don't think that using another variable like that will work.

Comment: what is the value of $numberOfRows?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129876/discussion-between-koko-and-user2519032).